# have clear screen clear konsole ram

Tags: kde, output, ram, konsole

how do I set it so clear command clears the output that was stored in ram

from my understanding, konsole keeps screen output in ram.

I want to clear that when I clear the visible part of the screen with the `clear` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the ram used by whatever running process is a facility rarely offered to the user.
More over, unless you precisely know the code the process is running, it is just impossible to know what is being stored where.

---

The visible part of the screen as well as some variable amount of lines that were previously displayed (1000 per default) are kept in the scrollback buffer that can be cleared altogether via the `View > Clear Scrollback and Reset` menu (or keying in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> if you kept default shortcuts) [(see §2.1.3)](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/konsole/konsole/konsole.pdf)

---

Keep in mind that while no log is kept by `konsole`, the user might well have :

- Copied parts of the screen into the clipboard, (*1)
- Saved parts of the screen into whatever file via the File > Save Output As menu option or whatever other mean offered by the shell,

Clearing these parts cannot obviously be achieved by `konsole`.

---

**1 :** Selectively clearing the clipboard history would be part of another topic.
This is actually possible from the command line thanks to `dbus`.
For example, if running `Klipper`, firing

```
qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper org.kde.klipper.klipper.clearClipboardHistory
```

would wipe it entirely.

---